# É possível exportar uma planilha em Excel com uma coluna configurada como "lista suspensa"?

Tags: r

Há alguma função que permita exportar em `.xlsx` uma planilha que tenha sido trabalhada no R?

Por exemplo, gostaria de algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `openxlsx::dataValidation` com a opção `type = "list"`. Os valores a serem usados para a lista precisam ser gravados em algum lugar do WorkBook e indicados para a função.

```
library(openxlsx)

candidatos <- data.frame(
  nome = c("João", "Maria", "José"),
  aprovado = NA)  # pode começar com valores pré-definidos ou vazios

valores <- c("sim", "não")

wb <- createWorkbook()

# Planilha com os dados
addWorksheet(wb, "Candidatos")
writeData(wb, "Candidatos", candidatos)

# Planilha separada para receber os valores
addWorksheet(wb, "valores")
writeData(wb, "valores", valores)

# Indica para usar os valores da planilha `valores` como lista:
dataValidation(wb, "Candidatos",
  col = 2, rows = seq_len(nrow(candidatos)) + 1,
  type = "list", value = "'valores'!$A$1:$A$2")

saveWorkbook(wb, "aprovados.xlsx")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Carlos Eduardo Lagosta. Atendeu perfeitamente às minhas necessidades.

Comment: No entanto, depois que fiz isso, me ocorreu uma outra necessidade. Coloquei a questão neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/551705/como-inserir-f%c3%b3rmula-com-operador-if-usando-o-pacote-openxlsx. Se tiveres disponibilidade para responder, agredeceria bastante. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado pelo auxílio com a questão da presente postagem