# Como inserir fórmula com operador "IF" usando o pacote "openxlsx"?

Tags: r

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/551312/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-exportar-uma-planilha-em-excel-com-uma-coluna-configurada-como-lista) o @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta explicou como inserir uma lista de opções dentro de uma célula de Excel através do pacote `openxlsx`.

Me ocorreu agora uma outra situação: como condicionar o preenchimento de uma célula com base na resposta da célula que contém a lista?

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
candidatos <- data.frame(
  item = c("Prova", "Curriculo", "Entrevista"),
  aprovado = NA,
  pontuacao_item = c("10", "7", "10"))

        item aprovado pontuacao_item
1      Prova       NA             10
2  Curriculo       NA              7
3 Entrevista       NA             10
```

Em seguida atribuo à coluna "aprovado" é uma lista com 2 valores: "sim" e "não", seguindo o procedimento sugerido pelo @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta.

Segue o código...

```
valores <- c("sim", "não")

wb <- createWorkbook()

# Planilha com os dados
addWorksheet(wb, "Candidatos")
writeData(wb, "Candidatos", candidatos)

# Planilha separada para receber os valores
addWorksheet(wb, "valores")
writeData(wb, "valores", valores)

# Indica para usar os valores da planilha `valores` como lista:
dataValidation(wb, "Candidatos",
               col = 2, rows = seq_len(nrow(candidatos)) + 1,
               type = "list", value = "'valores'!$A$1:$A$2")

saveWorkbook(wb, "aprovados.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

... e o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, estava refletindo sobre a possibilidade de criar uma outra coluna chamada "pontuacao_candidato" para ser preenchida em função da opção que se faz na coluna "aprovado".

Assim, se se escolher na planilha de Excel a opção "sim" na coluna "aprovado"; a coluna "pontuacao_candidato" deverá ser preenchida com o valor da coluna "pontuacao_item"; caso contrário, deverá ser preenchida com "0".

Procurei na [documentação do pacote](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5) mas não encontrei uma função que funcione como operador "IF". Optei, então, por "forçar" o preenchimento da célula como se faria se o processo fosse realizado no Excel, ou seja:

> =SE(B2="sim";C2;0)

Assim, usei a função `paste0` para criar uma fórmula para ser preenchida na planilha do Excel:

```
candidatos <- candidatos %>% 
  mutate(pontos = paste0("=SE(B", seq(2,nrow(candidatos)+1 ,1), '="sim";', candidatos$pontuacao_item, ';0)'))
```

Imaginei que o Excel executaria automaticamente a fórmula. Mas não foi o que aconteceu.
O resultado ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, com a redação da fórmula na célula

Quando clico na barra de "inserir função" e dou um enter, a fórmula funciona.

E o resultado fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, o inconveniente é que tenho que repetir o processo para todo as células.

Em suma, há alguma função dentro do próprio "openxlsx" que responda pelo operador "IF"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja a ajuda para `openxlsx::writeFormula`. Fórmulas são uma classe distinta, precisa indicar como tal ou serão entendidas como texto.

```
library(openxlsx)

candidatos <- data.frame(
  item = c("Prova", "Curriculo", "Entrevista"),
  aprovado = NA,
  pontuacao_item = c("10", "7", "10"),
  pontuacao_candidato = NA)

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "Candidatos")
writeData(wb, "Candidatos", candidatos)

addWorksheet(wb, "valores")
writeData(wb, "valores", c("sim", "não"))

linhas <- seq_len(nrow(candidatos)) + 1

form <- sprintf('IF(B%s = "sim", C%s, 0)', linhas, linhas)
writeFormula(wb, "Candidatos", form, 4, 2)

dataValidation(wb, "Candidatos", 2, linhas, "list", value = "'valores'!$A$1:$A$2")

saveWorkbook(wb, "aprovados.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Alternativamente, crie a coluna no *data.frame* com a fórmula e adicione a classe `formula` a ela (antes de grava-lo no WorkBook):

```
candidatos$pontuacao_candidato <- form
class(candidatos$pontuacao_candidato) <- c(class(candidatos$pontuacao_candidato), "formula")
```

**OBS1**: openxlsx só tem suporte para fórmulas em inglês.

**OBS2**: Não uso Excel. Testei o arquivo gerado no LibreOffice Calc, que usa `,` ao invés de `;` como separador nas fórmulas.

Comment: Muito obrigado (novamente) pelo auxílio Carlos. A sua solução é muito elegante e funcionou perfeitamente. Com relação à sua observação 2, tentei substituir a `,` por `;` (já que estou trabalhando no Excel) e deu erro. Só funcionou quando usei `,` mesmo, tal como está no seu código. Muito obrigado novamente