# Como gerar várias planilhas editáveis em Excel a partir de um dataset?

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gsheet)
library(openxlsx)
```

Preciso fazer a seleção de candidatos a um processo seletivo e preciso que os formulários de inscrição sejam distruibuídos entre alguns avaliadores. Esses avaliadores vão analisar os diversos documentos anexados no formulário e julgar se devem ser aceitos ou não. No caso de ser aceito, já existe uma pontuação pré-definida.

Para tanto, criei o seguinte fluxo:

- criei um formulario do Google Docs, onde o candidato pode anexar os documentos
- usei o pacote `gsheet` para baixar os dados
- manipulei os dados
- criei um *workbook* com o pacote `openxlsx`

A questão é que o interessante é que cada candidato seja um arquivo em Excel editável individual.
No entanto o máximo que consegui foi criar uma única planilha com várias folhas (uma por candidato) editáveis.

Segue meu código:

## Link das planilhas no Google Sheet

```
link_planilha <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hr2Xa9ARIbz6UlOdekAbb4Z5BEwBfG9jp_Mn5uF45c0/edit?resourcekey#gid=1068331489"

link_barema <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUu6h3t0potAaKtyXwqTW39yQsZSu9w66guWDTypE6Q/edit#gid=0"
```

## Baixar a planilha do barema do Google Docs

```
pontuacao_barema <- gsheet2tbl(link_barema)
```

## Formatação da planilha de curriculo

### Baixar a planilha do Google Docs

- acrescentar uma coluna "inscrição" que vai dar o número de inscrição do candidato por ordem de preenchimento
- fazer a pivotagem
- fazer o join com a planilha de pontuacao
- acrescentar as colunas "aceitar", "pontos" e "justificativa para não aceitação"
- usar a função `class()` para ajustar a coluna "link" para ser do tipo "hyperlink":

```
curriculo <- gsheet2tbl(link_planilha) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  mutate(inscricao = row_number()) %>% 
  select(inscricao, nome_do_candidato, starts_with("X")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x"),
               names_to = "item_importado",
               values_to = "link_documento") %>% 
  inner_join(pontuacao_barema, by = c("item_importado"="item")) %>% 
  mutate(aceitar = NA, 
         pontos = NA, 
         justificativa_nao_aceitacao = NA) %>% 
  relocate(pontuacao_item, .after = aceitar)


class(curriculo$link_documento) <- "hyperlink"


> curriculo
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  inscricao nome_do_candidato item_importado   link_documento         aceitar
      <int> <chr>             <chr>            <hyperlnk>             <lgl>  
1         1 Pedro Jorge       x1_minicurso_re~ https://drive.google.~ NA     
2         1 Pedro Jorge       x2_artigo_publi~ https://drive.google.~ NA     
3         1 Pedro Jorge       x2_diploma       https://drive.google.~ NA     
4         2 Carlos Roberto    x1_minicurso_re~ https://drive.google.~ NA     
5         2 Carlos Roberto    x2_artigo_publi~ https://drive.google.~ NA     
6         2 Carlos Roberto    x2_diploma       https://drive.google.~ NA     
7         3 Gilberto Barros   x1_minicurso_re~ https://drive.google.~ NA     
8         3 Gilberto Barros   x2_artigo_publi~ https://drive.google.~ NA     
9         3 Gilberto Barros   x2_diploma       https://drive.google.~ NA     
# ... with 3 more variables: pontuacao_item <chr>, pontos <lgl>,
#   justificativa_nao_aceitacao <lgl>
```

## Split da planilha

Como meu objetivo final é obter uma planilha por candidato, eu uso `split()` para separar meu dataset por candidato e agilizar a manipulação dos dados

```
curriculo_lista <- curriculo %>% 
  split(.$nome_do_candidato)
```

## Criar Workbook

Em seguida uso o pacote `openxlsx` para criar um *workbook*:

```
wb_curriculo <- createWorkbook()
```

## Configurando algumas células nas planilhas do *workbook*:

Como a intenção é entregar uma planilha dinâmica aos avaliadores, preciso deixar as células previamente configuradas

### Configurando a coluna "aceitar":

Uma das coisas que preciso é que a coluna "aceitar" seja configurada para apresentar duas opções: "sim" e "não"
Para tanto, seguindo sugestão [deste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/551312/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-exportar-uma-planilha-em-excel-com-uma-coluna-configurada-como-lista/551580#551580):

1. criei uma *worksheet* chamada "valores"

```
addWorksheet(wb = wb_curriculo, 
             sheetName = "valores")
```

2. Atribuí a essa planilha dois valores: "sim" e "não":

```
  writeData(wb = wb_curriculo, 
            sheet = "valores", 
            x = c("sim", "não"))
```

### Configurando a coluna "pontos":

Outra coisa que necessito é que a coluna "pontos" esteja condicionada ao que vai ser escolhido na coluna "aceitar"

- Se "sim", deve retornar o valor da coluna "pontuacao_item"
- Se "não", deve retornar um espaço em branco

```
linhas <- seq_len(nrow(curriculo)) + 1

formula_condicional_pontos <- sprintf('IF(E%s = "sim", F%s, " ")', linhas, linhas)
```

## Criar o loop:

Como estou trabalhando com uma lista e preciso que as configurações sejam aplicadas à cada planilha, usei o seguinte *loop*:

```
  for (i in 1:length(curriculo_lista)) {
    
    # Criar uma worksheet para cada elemento da lista
    
    addWorksheet(wb = wb_curriculo, 
                 sheetName=names(curriculo_lista[i]))
    
    # Registrar nessa planilha o dataset de cada elemento da lista
    
    writeData(wb = wb_curriculo, 
              sheet=names(curriculo_lista[i]), 
              x=curriculo_lista[[i]])
    
    #  Atribuir à coluna "aceitar" (coluna 5) o menu drop-down a ser preenchido com os elementos da planilha "valores"
    
    dataValidation(wb = wb_curriculo, 
                   sheet = names(curriculo_lista[i]), 
                   col = 5, 
                   rows = seq_len(nrow(curriculo)) + 1,
                   type = "list", 
                   value = "'valores'!$A$1:$A$2")
    
    # Escrever a fórmula para a formatacao condicional da coluna "pontos"
    
    writeFormula(wb = wb_curriculo, 
                 sheet = names(curriculo_lista[i]), 
                 x = formula_condicional_pontos, 
                 startRow = 2,
                 startCol = 7)
  }
```

## Salvar o *workbook*

```
saveWorkbook(wb = wb_curriculo, 
             file = "curriculo_teste_inscricao.xlsx", 
             returnValue = T,
             overwrite = T)
```

## O resultado:

No *workbook* resultante é possível ver que cada candidato ficou em uma planilha (além da planilha "valores" que serve para alimentar a o menu drop-down da coluna "aceitar")

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Finalmente, a dúvida:

Como criar vários **workbooks** (ao invés de *worksheets*), sendo cada *workbook* com o nome de um candidato?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis que consegui com o seguinte *loop*:

```
for(i in 1:length(curriculo_lista)){
    
    
    wb <- createWorkbook(title = sprintf("%s", names(curriculo_lista[i])))
    
    
    addWorksheet(wb = wb, 
                 sheetName=names(curriculo_lista[i]))
    
    writeData(wb = wb, 
              sheet=names(curriculo_lista[i]), 
              x=curriculo_lista[[i]])
    
    addWorksheet(wb = wb, 
                 sheetName= 'valores')
    
    writeData(wb = wb,
              sheet= 'valores', 
              x= c("sim", "não"))  
    
    dataValidation(wb = wb, 
                   sheet = names(curriculo_lista[i]), 
                   col = 5, 
                   rows = seq_len(nrow(curriculo)) + 1,
                   type = "list", 
                   value = "'valores'!$A$1:$A$2")
    
    
    linhas <- seq_len(nrow(curriculo)) + 1
    formula_condicional_pontos <- sprintf('IF(E%s = "sim", F%s, " ")', linhas, linhas)
    
    
    writeFormula(wb = wb, 
                 sheet = names(curriculo_lista[i]), 
                 x = formula_condicional_pontos, 
                 startRow = 2,
                 startCol = 7)
    
    
    
    
    saveWorkbook(wb, 
                 file = sprintf("curriculo_de_%s.xlsx", names(curriculo_lista[i])),
                 overwrite = T)  
  }
```

Como saída, tive os três *workbooks*, cada um contendo a planilha 'valores' e a planilha com o nome do candidato